# npm ERR! code EPERM when "npx live-server"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-live-server

I am trying to do "npx live-server ." but it failed. It might be the problem of my username(with whitespaces). So that I follow the steps from [npm - EPERM mkdir: operation not permitted on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55450386/npm-eperm-mkdir-operation-not-permitted-on-windows).
I changed my username in local machine and then
run  `npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global`

but in git bash, it still shows the original username with whitespace. Could anyone help me with this please!!!
[image]

[image]

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this in terminal by opening it as administrator.[image]